# Не выводит на экран

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Код

```
include 'C:\Users\LikeToProgram\Desktop\FASM\INCLUDE\WIN32W.INC'

org 100h
call start
call exit

num1 db ?
num2 db ?
msg db 'Enter a number: $'

proc    start
        push num1
        call getNum
        push num2
        call getNum
        call count
        pop dx
        mov ah, 02h
        int 21h
        ret

endp

proc getNum

        mov ah, 09h
        mov dx, msg
        int 21h

        pop dx
        mov ah, 01h
        int 21h
        ret

endp

proc    count

        sub [num1], 48
        sub [num2], 48
        mov al, [num1]
        add al, [num2]
        add al, 48
        push ax
        ret
endp

proc    exit

        mov ax, 4C00h
        int 21h
        ret

endp
```

При запуске, дает ввести 2 числа, а потом просто заканчивается. Почему не происходит вызов последнего прерывания? Хотя я уверен что проблема в передаче по стеку.

Comment: int 21h - это способ ввода-вывода в DOS (не в смысле "консольное окно", а именно операционная система DOS). Вы, судя по include, собираете виндовое приложение - нужен другой способ вывода. Либо собирать приложение "как 16-битное досовское" в .COM вместо .EXE, тогда будет запущен эмулятор.

Comment: И внутри процедуры после call не стоит делать pop - последним на стек положили адрес возврата (команда call), его нужно там же и оставить. Надо косвенно адресовать "прошлые" ячейки стека через регистр esp/sp.

Comment: @yeputons, подключаемый файл на тип собираемого файла сам по себе не влияет, там просто набор макросов. По-умолчанию fasm собирает бинарный файл в 16-битном режиме ассемблера, ну и по `org 100h` он еще понимает, что нужно добавить файлу расширение `.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, у вас действительно проблема с передачей параметров.

Для примера возьмем соглашение stdcall. Параметры передаются в процедуру через стек в обратном порядке (от последнего порядка до первого), внутри процедуры адреса параметров будут `sp+2` для первого параметра, `sp+4` - для второго, и т.д. При этом по адресу `sp+0` лежит адрес возврата из процедуры, поэтому если в процедуре сделать просто `pop dx` (как у вас в процедуре `start`), адрес возврата из стека заберется, и команда `ret` найдет на стеке не адрес возврата, а что-то другое, и выход из процедуры произойдет по неправильному адресу.

Возврат значения из процедуры выполняется через регистр `ax`. Если вместо этого перед `ret` положить что-то на стек (у вас `push ax` в процедуре `count`), то команда `ret` посчитает это адресом возврата, и опять же возврат произойдет по неправильному адресу.

Как делать правильно:

Передаем параметр через стек, вызываем процедуру, внутри процедуры создаем стековый фрейм (команды `push bp`, `mov bp, sp`), дальше внутри процедуры адресуем параметры от регистра `bp`: `[bp+4]` - первый параметр (+4 а не +2 потому что теперь на стеке еще лежит сохраненное значение регистра `bp`), `[bp+6]` - второй и т.д. Перед выходом из процедуры кладем возвращаемое значение в регистр `ax`, восстанавливаем из стека старое значение регистра `bp` (`pop bp`), возвращаем управление командой `ret 2` (число должно быть 2*количество переданных в процедуру параметров). Ну и после выхода из процедуры забираем возвращенное значение из регистра `ax`.

Вопрос - зачем пляска с `bp`, если по идее можно было адресовать параметры через регистр `sp`? Все просто: в 16-битном режиме нельзя использовать `sp` в качестве базового адреса, в отличие от `bp` или `bx`. Плюс еще внутри стекового фрейма можно создавать локальные переменные.

Подробнее о передаче параметров: [**Передача параметров через стек**](https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/025-peredacha-parametrov-cherez-stek/)

В целом рекомендую для изучения [учебник по ассемблеру на fasmworld.ru](https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnik/).

Кстати, вместо `win32w.inc` для добавления макросов `proc` и `endp` в программах под dos лучше использовать файл `proc16.inc` из этого же учебника: [**Макросы PROC и ENDP**](https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/029-makrosy-proc-i-endp/). Тогда, например, можно будет явно объявлять параметры процедур и обращаться к ним по имени, а не через `[bp+число]`.

Рабочий код, с некоторыми поправками и комментариями:

```
include 'WIN32W.INC'

org 100h

start:
    call getNum
    mov [num1], al
    
    call getNum
    mov [num2], al
    
    call count
    
    push ax
    call printNum
    
    call exit

num1 db ?
num2 db ?
msg db 'Enter a number: $'

proc getNum
    ; Данная процедура не принимает никаких параметров,
    ; а просто возвращает введенное число в регистре al
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, msg
    int 21h

    ; Функция 01h прерывания 21h просто возвращает введенный символ в регистре al
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    sub al, 48 ; Сразу преващаем код символа в число
    
    ret
endp

proc printNum
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    
    mov dl, [bp+4]
    add dl, 48 ; Превращаем цифру в символ только на этапе вывода
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    
    pop bp
    ret 2
endp

proc count
    ; Просто складываем числа, ничего лишнего
    mov al, [num1]
    add al, [num2]
    ; Результат уже находится в регистре al, дополнительно ничего делать не нужно
    ret
endp

proc exit
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
    ret
endp
```

Единственный минус - весь вывод идет в одну строку, с переносами на новую строку постарайтесь разобраться самостоятельно)

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: На asmworld учил в начале, а потом... Решил по книжкам. Кстати, на asmworld'e в коментах xss-уязвимость есть)

Comment: @Razor, по поводу уязвимости лучше автору сайта написать. По поводу обучения - я считаю Asmworld одним из лучших ресурсов для обучения ассемблеру под DOS, там очень хорошо последовательно все разъясняется (не в стиле "как нарисовать сову").